# transform-origin gives @keyframes animation unintended delay

Tags: html, css

When I click the box and trigger this animation, it has a weird delay after the animation is played and before the top and bottom bar get to their desired end positions. I assume this is because of the `transform-origin` but not so sure. How can I make the animation to run smooth?

```css
.box{
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  float:left; margin: 20px;
}
.box label{
  display: block;
  width: 50px; margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translateY(80px); 
  text-align: center;
}
.box span{
  display: block;
  width: 50px; height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input{display: none;}
input:checked+label span{ animation-play-state: running;}


#bars02:checked+label span{
  animation-play-state: running;
  transition: .5s;
}

#bars02:checked+label span:nth-child(1){
  animation: rotatePlus .5s forwards;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

#bars02+label span{
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes rotatePlus{
  0%{ transform:rotate(0); }
  100%{ transform: rotate(35deg); }
}
#bars02:checked+label span{
  animation-play-state: running;
  transition: .5s;
}

#bars02:checked+label span:nth-child(3){
  transform-origin: left top;
  animation: rotateMinus .5s forwards;
}

#bars02:checked+label span:nth-child(2){
  animation: opacity .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateMinus{
  0%{ transform:rotate(0); }
  100%{ transform: rotate(-35deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bars02">
  <label for="bars02">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a Chrome bug. You can simplify your code like below and set the `transform-origin` initially

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box label {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translateY(80px);
  text-align: center;
}

.box span {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: .5s;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label span:nth-child(1) {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
label span:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

#bars02:checked+label span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

#bars02:checked+label span:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bars02">
  <label for="bars02">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
</div>
```